# How do i save the same token for each user that visits my page PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I save a token for each user that visits my site so that when I select the items , I use that token to get the items that the user added? I was trying to save the token into a variable but that functions runs only once . I have one table and I wont be implementing a login system yet ; this is just for guests. I want each user to have one unique token that I could use to select user's items .

I tried using session storage imgur.com/C3FhmV1 and my db imgur.com/10RjR9f but it didn't work out well.

Thank you

```
        //
        function RandomStr($length = 10)
        {
            session_start();
            $state = $_SESSION['state'] ?? false;
            if ($state) return;

            $_SESSION['state'] = true;

            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
            }

            return $randomString;
        }

       $userId = RandomStr();
       echo $userId;


 $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (productname,productmodel,productquantity,token,productcolor,productprice)
            values ('$productname','$productmodel','$productquantity','$userId','$productcolor','$productprice')";
        //
```

Comment: Sounds like exactly what [HTTP Cookie's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) were intended for.

Comment: @Dharman yes i know that .  I will be implementing prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Cookies!

Whenever a user visit your site for first, set a random/unique token in their Cookies and use same to identify cart items.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use js

```
<script>
if(localStorage.getItem("guestId").length() < 1 ){  //undefined || null
//means he is a new guest
localStorage.setItem("guestId",<?php echo $yourUserId;?>);
//assigned a permanent id fo the guest. valid till hard reload or browserchange.
}else{
//you already have the users unique id inside localStorage so.
var guestId = localStorage.getItem("guestId");
// use ajax here or simply reload page with 
location.href = "mypage.php?user="+guestId;
}
</script>
//Note: this will raise a lot of security issue.
```